# How do I validate a token coming from a third party using the same ADFS authentication server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, adfs

An application A (me) needs to communicate with Application B and the communication needs to be secured using ADFS (OAuth2 Client credentials grant flow). Both A and B get their tokens using the same ADFS authentication server.

Reading the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios#client-credentials-grant-flow), it's pretty clear to me how my application A need to get a token from the authentication server and send it to the application B.

However, what I don't understand is how I can validate a token received by Application B.

I also struggle finding examples showing endpoints and JSONs. Is there any resource I can double check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate the JWT, look [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/validating-an-adfs-jwt-a47099b014b9).

Basically check issuer, aud, expiry, signature etc.

jwt.io has a bunch of libraries to do this.

Comment: Yeah, itwas my suspicion that JWT was the solution. One quick question: the information like issuer, aud etc. is related to the Application B and not A, since the token was requested by App B with its client id and secret, right?

Comment: Thanks, we can close this :)